# Not able to add scroll to a view with a gridview in it

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a problem creating an app in which it requires a two coloumn gridview and a imageflipper layout on top of it as shown below.

[image]

The problem is that  the whole view should be scrollable. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed this way

```
  <Scrollview>
     <view>
         <imageflipper />
        <gridview />
       <view>
  </scrollview>
```

But I had to set the height of the gridview manualy.It has some issues with earlier android versions.Also I had to customise my scroll view so that I can handel horizontal swipe of the imageflipper

Answer (score 2):

Scroll view allows only one child. So you try putting your two coloumn gridview and the imageflipper layout inside a view or layout and put that in a scrollview.That way there is only one child inside the scrollview.

```
  <Scrollview>
     <view>
        <gridview 1/>
        <gridview 2/>
        <imageflipper />
     <view>
  </scrollview>
```

Comment: I tried this but it wont work as the adapter wont load any data until the grid is scrolled

Comment: are u using the stock gridview?